# How to use Twilio Flex for 'bot to human handoff' when my webchat interface isn't built using Twilio?

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, chatbot, livechat, twilio-programmable-chat

I have already built a webchat for my website using Dialogflow. I want to add the feature of talking with a human agent as and when the customer wants. How do I achieve this using Twilio Flex? When the customer asks the bot to connect him/her to a human agent, the bot should be able to shift the control of the chat to a human agent who's online on Twilio Flex panel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have some code you have tried that you can share?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll likely want to move the chat messages you've had with the Dialogflow agent into a Twilio Chat channel and then connect that to Flex by creating a new Task. Have you considered [importing your Dialogflow bot to Autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/twilio-autopilot-cli#importing-dialogflow-agents) so that you can continue to work within Twilio?

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a good answer for this? I am in the same boat